# ¿Cómo traer valor de Array - MongoDB con PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

Buenas tardes, tengo los siguientes documentos en la colección usuarios.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f4be355b22a754991afc0f"),
    "nombre" : "Jairo Andrés",
    "edad" : 18,
    "pais" : "Colombia"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f4be505b22a754991afc10"),
    "nombre" : "Alejandra",
    "edad" : 19,
    "pais" : "Colombia"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f4be6c5b22a754991afc11"),
    "nombre" : "Carlos Antonio",
    "edad" : 26,
    "pais" : "Perú"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f4be7c5b22a754991afc12"),
    "nombre" : "Daniela",
    "edad" : 15,
    "pais" : "Argentina"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f4c39f5b22a754991afc13"),
    "nombre" : "Pepito Perez",
    "edad" : 19,
    "frutas" : [ 
        "Pera", 
        "Manzana", 
        "Banano"
    ]
}
```

Y tengo el siguiente código PHP:

```
<?php

    $mongo = new MongoClient();

    $db = $mongo->selectDB("example");

    $c_usuarios = $mongo->selectCollection($db, "usuarios");


    if($c_usuarios->count()>0){
        $row = $c_usuarios->find();
        foreach($row as $nameUsuario){
            echo $nameUsuario["nombre"] . " " . $nameUsuario["edad"] . " " . $nameUsuario["frutas"] . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Me muestra el nombre y edad, pero el de frutas me sale array.

> Notice: Undefined index: frutas in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\index.php
>   on line 13 Jairo Andrés 18
>
> Notice: Undefined index: frutas in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\index.php
>   on line 13 Alejandra 19
>
> Notice: Undefined index: frutas in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\index.php
>   on line 13 Carlos Antonio 26
>
> Notice: Undefined index: frutas in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\index.php
>   on line 13 Daniela 15
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\example\index.php on line 13 Pepito Perez 19 Array

PD: Soy nuevo en MongoDB con PHP, Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date cuenta que los primeros registros no tienen una clave `frutas` asociada, eso explica la advertencia `Notice: Undefined index: frutas`.

La forma de traer datos del array variará dependiendo de la manera en que quieras mostrarlo. Por ejemplo, en tu caso, suponiendo que solo quieres listarlo, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
<?php

if($c_usuarios->count()>0){
        $row = $c_usuarios->find();
        foreach($row as $nameUsuario){
            echo $nameUsuario["nombre"] . " " . $nameUsuario["edad"] . " " . (isset($nameUsuario["frutas"]) ? implode(', ', $nameUsuario["frutas"]) : '') . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Antes de concatenar el valor del índice "frutas", comprobamos que se ha establecido mediante el operador ternario ?:,  si lo está, concatenamos todos sus valores haciendo uso de `implode` para evitar el mensaje "Array to string conversion", y si no lo está, usamos una cadena vacía para no alterar el resultado.

Comment: Excelente, es lo que necesitaba. Gracias